# How to extract URL's in quotes by using regex

Tags: regex, windows, url, extract

I have a text which is a damaged sqlite 3 database, it has lots of url's, mostly all of them are in quotes. What would be the best way to extract them without losing any parts of the URL ?

Links contain all kinds of characters, 50% of the links are from search engines with 100 characters, etc.

This text file is a damaged sqlite 3 database.

[How it looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ewwW.png)

***"url":"http://www.bing.com/search?q=test"***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are on unix, the following should do it

```
strings sqllite.txt | grep '\"http[^\"]*"' | tr '"' '\n' | grep 'http' | sort | uniq > extracted_urls.txt
```

Where sqllite is the database file.  Just tested on RHEL.  The sort and uniq is just to remove duplicate URLs.

EDIT: New expression to ignore the favicons in the file

```
strings sqllite.txt | grep '\"url\":\"http[^\"]*"' | tr ',' '\n' | grep '\"url\":\"http' | tr '"' '\n' | grep 'http' | sort | uniq > extracted_urls.txt
```

Comment: @rudolphd I think so, but I can't test it right now.  Might need a syntax tweak if it fails.

Comment: Just tested and it didn't work, nothing showed up after running this.. I checked the folder and it's the right one, because it doesn't show "no such file or dir."

Comment: I just edited the answer because the problem may be that the file is a binary file, not a text file, or certain characters may have caused a problem for my initial answer.

Comment: Now it's working, I had to install apt-cyg to get installer working, then I downloaded binutils through apt-cyg which contains strings command. The only problem is that it shows everything in the same console. Is there a way to output it to a file ?

Comment: NVM. Found by myself, the final command would look like this - cat file.txt | strings | grep '\"http[^\"]*"' | tr '"' '\n' | grep 'http' | sort | uniq > extracted.txt

Comment: I will update the answer with your re-direct as that is what most people would want.

Comment: I have another question regarding this subject.. Is it possible to extract url that's in quotes and has "url=" in the beginning ? >>> "url":"http://url" <<< (I don't know why there's ; this symbol, but it shouldn't be there)  Because when I use this method which extracts all URLs, it also extracts favicon urls.

Comment: Can you edit your question and at the bottom, add an example of the line you don't want and say so.  I'll try to update the answer to cope with that.